# How to add a custom icon to Angular2 Clarity-icons?

Tags: angular, svg

I have decided to try out Angular 2 and came across Clarity which provides some very good UI features, one of which is an out of the box suite of Icons "clarity-icons".
These icons are defined in node_modules\clarity-icons\src\svg-icon-templates.ts
They are declared in an array of SVG icons which is very clear and easy to follow so thought this would be an easy way and place to add a custom svg icon, however I do not know how to actually use this new icon?
1, How do I build this new ts file? I tried "npm build" etc and nothing the package.json had no targets, I am guessing you are not supposed to edit files in the node_modules sub directory? 
2, If I did build it would it be overwritten when I next do a clean install?

Basically, I want to use the clarity-icon package as I like and want to use some of the existing icons, but I want another icon to be added rather than linking it in seperatly as I want clarity to handle the size/colour etc for me.

I also considered that rather than use the shape annotation I could link to an svg file and use the clr-icon tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a high level, adding your own icon to the Clarity Icons library only requires using the following call somewhere in your application (as of 0.8.0)...

```
ClarityIcons.add({"shapeNameGoesHere": "<svg ... >[your SVG code goes here]</svg>"});
```

ClarityIcons is available off the window object in Javascript. It's a global API for the Icons library.

That will (or should) allow you to use the `dir` and `size` attributes in the `clr-icon` element easily enough if you create your image for a "0 0 36 36" viewbox.

To use the decorator classes, you'll need to create different paths for the solid, badged, and alerted versions of your icon. That's a little deeper than you may want to go though.

[clarity](/questions/tagged/clarity)[clarity-icons](/questions/tagged/clarity-icons)

Comment: for me i needed to change double quotes  " to single quotes ' after then it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

This works for me with clarity version 0.11.8 and beyond with angular-CLI. 
Create a service **custom-icons.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {ClarityIcons} from "@clr/icons"; 
@Injectable()
export class CustomClarityIcons {
  icons: any = {
    "sample-icon": '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" \t viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve"> <g> \t<path d="M31.1,23.1c-1.2,0-3.3-0.7-4.1-5.1C25.5,9.7,26,3.4,16.5,3l0,0c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0l0,0 \t\tC6,3.4,6.3,9.5,5,18c-0.7,4.5-2.8,5.1-4.1,5.1C0.4,23.1,0,23,0,23v6h32v-6C32,23,31.6,23.1,31.1,23.1z M30,27H2v-2 \t\tc1.7-0.4,4.2-1.8,5-6.7c0.1-0.9,0.3-1.9,0.4-2.7c1-7,1.4-10.2,8.2-10.6h0.3l0,0l0,0h0.4c6.6,0.3,7.1,3.4,8.1,10.2 \t\tc0.2,1,0.3,2.1,0.5,3.2c0.9,4.9,3.3,6.3,5,6.7L30,27L30,27z"/> \t<rect x="13.8" width="4.5" height="2"/> \t<rect x="12" y="30" width="8" height="2"/> </g> <polygon points="22.4,13.1 20.3,11 16,15.2 11.8,11 9.7,13.1 13.9,17.4 9.7,21.6 11.8,23.7 16,19.5 20.3,23.7 22.4,21.6 18.1,17.4 \t"/></svg>' 
  }
  public load() {
    ClarityIcons.add(this.icons)
  }
}
```

Then do inject this into your component something like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomClarityIcons } from '../custom-clarity-icons';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private customClarityIcons : CustomClarityIcons ) {
    customClarityIcons .load(); //injecting custom-icons here to app component so that can be used across the aplication
  }
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to remove  "../node_modules/clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.js"  from scripts section that includes clarity-icons.js. in angula-cli.json to avoid running two instances of ClarityIcons.  Also add CustomClarityIcons  in app.module.ts Then in your HTML simply do this

```
<clr-icon shape="sample-icon"></clr-icon>
```